# Why were movies in the past produced at a faster pace than modern movies?

Tags: production

In the past movies were produced pretty fast. For example Charlie Chaplin made about 5-10 movies a year, often being actor, director and producer in one person.

Today a movie often takes many months until completion.

Why were movies in the past produced at a faster pace and why does modern film production of a movie seem to be so much slower in comparison?

Comment: I'd imagine there are a lot more things that need to be done to complete a modern movie. In the 1920's you didn't have to deal with lawyers to fight for rights to use different intellectual properties. Deal with executives who want to change the view of a director. Deal with expensive and tough to work with actors. Not to mention the amount of editing and refining that are done in movies now. It would also help that movies from the 1920's where silent, and didn't often last for longer then an hour. High budget films that are 2-3 hours with 500+ people working on it take time.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, why don't you make this an answer?

Comment: @Mnementh Probably because good answers cite sources and that can take a lot more time. If it were posted as is, I'd likely downvote because it makes a lot of (logical and probably accurate) claims without backing them up.

Comment: @Catija [citation needed] - Randall Munroe uses that tag sometimes at trivial stuff to make fun of it. I think most people agree movies back then were silent, a bit shorter and had lesser people involved. This are basically onewhos arguments. So I don't think he need to back this claims up, but it can never hurt to do so.

Comment: Citation or not, it could still use a little more fleshing out, be it just to elaborate on the undoubtedly valid points a little more. While the reasoning makes sense, it would just somehow be a pity to answer such a rather fundamental question with a mere single 5-lines paragraph (but that is admittedly only my entirely subjective feeling on the matter). ;-)

Comment: @Mnementh On your part, it might be worth it to look at films from the 50s and 60s... I don't know that our schedule is particularly different from that era (though post-production is certainly a bigger issue). Even the [most](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000348/?ref_=nv_sr_1) popular [actors](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000030/?ref_=nv_sr_1) only appeared in 1-3 films a year. So that sort of argues that the silent era was the outlier, not the current film era.

Comment: But I'd also wager (entirely uninformed, though) that the process was a little bit more streamlined (if not to say assembly-line like), i.e. faster, during the reign of the Hollywood Studio System.

Comment: Just to clarify are you asking specifically about the filming of a movie, or the overall production of a movie from beginning to end? I think my answer as it stands right now only focuses on the filming aspect. It's possible the overall production time of a movie might be greater now then in the 1920's given the reasons I stated before.

Comment: Am I the only one who thought, just from the title, that it was referring to the fps?

Answer (score 17):

Original Answer: I'd imagine there are a lot more things that need to be done to complete a modern movie. In the 1920's you didn't have to deal with lawyers to fight for rights to use different intellectual properties. Deal with executives who want to change the view of a director. Deal with expensive and tough to work with actors. Not to mention the amount of editing and refining that are done in movies now. It would also help that movies from the 1920's where silent, and didn't often last for longer then an hour. High budget films that are 2-3 hours with 500+ people working on it take time.

After looking further, while there appears to be this perception that older movies where quicker to produce this may not be the case. See [Charlie Chaplin and "The Gold Rush"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlie_Chaplin#A_Woman_of_Paris_and_The_Gold_Rush), which was an

> elaborate production, costing almost $1 million, included location shooting in the Truckee mountains with 600 extras, extravagant sets, and special effects. The last scene was not shot until May 1925, after 15 months of filming.

Meanwhile a more modern movie like [Interstellar started filming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)#Filming) on

> August 6, 2013, in the province of Alberta.

and

> Filming concluded in December 2013

meaning it only took about 4-5 months to shoot. So with this evidence it might be a misconception that older movies were quicker to produce. It might come down to the overall scope of the film, as well as the difficulties within the film's production.

Comment: See, and that's why looking up some citations is useful... you can find out you're wrong. :D

Comment: Nice finds. So my assumption is already wrong.

Comment: @Mnementh: note that in a production like Star Wars principal photography is generally a fraction of the total work needed, which spans well *before* and *after* the weeks where the cameras are actually rolling.

Answer (score 5):

There was no television in the silent era, but audiences had a voracious appetite for films, so most studios tried to pump out movies as quickly as possible. However, depending on the year and the studio, films still might be produced quicker or slower than average. For instance, Laurel & Hardy spent about a month working on their silent films, although these were only two-reel (20 minute) comedies.

When Charlie Chaplin got into features, he spent three years each on his *The Gold Rush*, *The Circus* and *City Lights*. He was a perfectionist, and filmed scenes over and over. He scrapped whole scenes that he didn't like after spending days filming them. He also took vacations and put the films on hiatus when he couldn't find comic inspiration.

However, when he worked at Keystone in 1914, he might appear in 2-3 short comedies a month. These were filmed quickly, with barely a scenario and a lot of improvisation. Chaplin was happy when he worked at Mutual in 1916-1917, and he could devote a month or two to a two-reel comedy.

Most of the special effects in silent films (there could be quite a few), were actually done in-camera. The post-production part of filmmaking was editing, tinting (sometimes), preparing alternate negatives for foreign releases, and possibly preparing a score for the film. Only major films had an official music score, and only a few theaters actually used them.

If you look at the end credits of a modern movie, you will notice that there are all kinds of jobs credited like caterers, accountants, lawyers, hairdressers, animators and so on. While these jobs existed in the silent era, modern films and studios have a lot more bureaucracy that takes a lot more time. Also, modern studios are not geared up to produce as many films as quickly as possible these days. That does happen for episodic television though.